# detect if div has rotated 30deg

Tags: javascript, css

I am working with css3, My problem is how to detect if a div has rotated 30 degree using javascript. Could anyone help me on this? Thank you that much!
here is my code:

```
    if($('.page').css('-ms-transform", rotateY(-30deg)')){
    alert("something here");
    }
```

Comment: I guess you could setup a timer and rotate in steps.